# Trying to display texture of avatar properly

Tags: three.js, textures, blender, avatar

I exported an avatar from Make Human (version 1.0 alpha 6), imported it on Blender (v2.75) and then exported it to three.js(r71). Now I am trying to display the avatar using webgl, but the texture of brows, eyes and eyelashes are weird (textures were not loaded properly) and I don't know what the problem is (see avatar image below). How to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: A few more code would be welcome to answer :)

Comment: The issue is related to Blender configuration, that is why I didn't post any code.

Comment: I used three.js example [webgl_morphtargets_human](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets_human) and replaced the existing avatar with an exported Make Human avatar.

Answer (score 0):

Might it be that those textures had transparency in them, and your final product is unable to use them (this is very typical for eye lashes)

Comment: How can I disable transparency then?

Comment: well, you probaply cannt, transparancy like in gif and png files is a pixel with no color. However i think you got a good notion of where those textures should be, and maybe with some photoshoping/ gimp.. you could place those textures directly on your base human texture. then you remove also the lash mesh (probaply a simple plane) .
Another aprouch to do lashes is to create individual meshes for them